# How can I instruct yum to install a specific version of package X?

Tags: package-management, yum

If there are two (or more) versions of a given RPM available in a YUM repository, how can I instruct `yum` to install the version I want?

Looking through the Koji build service I notice that there are several versions.

[image: ss #1]

Answer (score 483, accepted):

To see what particular versions are available to you via `yum` you can use the `--showduplicates` switch . It gives you a list like "package name.architecture           version":

```
$ yum --showduplicates list httpd | expand
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.steadfast.net

Available Packages
httpd.x86_64                        2.4.6-6.fc20                         fedora 
httpd.x86_64                        2.4.10-1.fc20                        updates
```

As far as installing a particular version? You can append the version info to the name of the package, removing the architecture name, like so:

```
$ sudo yum install <package name>-<version info>
```

For example in this case if I wanted to install the older version, 2.4.6-6 I'd do the following:

```
$ sudo yum install httpd-2.4.6-6
```

You can also include the release info when specifying a package. In this case since I'm dealing with Fedora 20 (F20) the release info would be "fc20", and the architecture info too.

```
$ sudo yum install httpd-2.4.6-6.fc20
$ sudo yum install httpd-2.4.6-6.fc20.x86_64
```

#### repoquery

If you're ever unsure that you're constructing the arguments right you can consult with `repoquery` too.

```
$ sudo yum install yum-utils  # (to get `repoquery`)
$ repoquery --show-duplicates httpd-2.4*
httpd-0:2.4.6-6.fc20.x86_64
httpd-0:2.4.10-1.fc20.x86_64
```

#### downloading & installing

You can also use one of the following options to download a particular RPM from the web, and then use `yum` to install it.

```
$ yum --downloadonly <package>
-or-
$ yumdownloader <package>
```

And then install it like so:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall <path to rpm>
```

What if I want to download everything that package X requires?

```
$ yumdownloader --resolve <package>
```

#### Example

```
$ yumdownloader --resolve vim-X11
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vim-X11.x86_64 2:7.3.315-1.fc14 set to be reinstalled
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
vim-X11-7.3.315-1.fc14.x86_64.rpm                              | 1.1 MB     00:01
```

Notice it's doing a dependency check, and then downloading the missing pieces. See my answer that covers it in more details here: [How to download a file from repo, and install it later w/o internet connection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89222/how-to-download-a-file-from-repo-and-install-it-later-w-o-internet-connection/89250#89250).

#### References

- [Get yum to install a specific package version](https://www.zulius.com/how-to/yum-install-specific-package-version/)

Comment: I don't think it work for packages between the latest version located `@updates` and the initial version for the OS located `@fedora`. For example if you try to install `httpd-2.4.8-1`, `yum` would say package not available.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - not following. That version doesn't show as being available in the repo.

Comment: Let me try again with a real example from my yum log. `python-libs-2.7.5-12.fc20.x86_64` was once installed on my computer but has since been replaced. Assuming now I want to install this specific package, `yumdownloader python-libs-2.7.5-12*` would say `No Match for argument python-libs-2.7.5-12*
Nothing to download`. What I am trying to say is that once a new package arrive, the old one would no longer be accessible from yum. You can only install the latest package or the initial version, but not versions in between.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - In that scenario I think you have to use `yum downgrade ...` if the package was already installed and you're attempting to go back to it later. In my Q I was attempting to show how one would hand select a particular version of a package that hadn't been installed yet. http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch05s06s03.html

Comment: No, it doesn't work even when upgrading to a specific package. I have experimented this with a fresh installation just a few days ago. You can only yum update to the latest package and not any version you desire.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - I'm not using `yum update`, I used `yum install`.

Comment: Yes, it applies to yum install too. I got a list of installed programs with `rpm -qa | sort > installed`. Then after setting up the OS on my test server, I did `yum install $(cat /tmp/installed)`. Some of the packages did not get installed because they are no longer available.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - in my scenario of this Q I'm installing package X which had never been installed before. We actually just used this method for my day job so I know that this whole thing worked in that scenario. Let me think about how to incorporate the scenario of "packageX was already installed" into this Q. I might rephrase the Q so that it's more specific to cut out your particular point.

Comment: I am not sure how it is possible to install an older version of a package using yum even when you have not installed the package previously. I thought the mirror @updates do not keep older versions of the same software. Am I missing some repository?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - in my 20+ years of using RH (RPM + YUM) I'd generally discourage you from ever doing a `rpm -qa | sort > /tmp/installed` and then trying to replay that list into a new server. That's just not the appropriate way to make use of `rpm` or `yum`, IMO.

Comment: Ok, what do you suggest is the proper way to get the same packages installed?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - I answered that Q before, at least have memories of it here. Search for it, I will as well, but it's 4:30am in the morning where I live and I'm trying to go to bed now 8-).

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - here's one of the Q's that I remembered: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146159/centos-rpm-qa-vs-yum-list-installed/146398#146398

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - there's this Q too that could use some updating with the method shown in the other Q, if you're looking for something to do 8-) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71/duplicating-a-linux-installation-yum-based

Comment: @slm - this worked great for httpd, but didn't work when I tried to install a specific version of OpenJDK using `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1:1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el6_5`. Is it due to the hyphens in the package name?

Comment: @coderplus I think you need to omit the `1:` prefix from the version string.

Comment: In my case yum didn't accept version with the release, e. g. `yum install MariaDB-server-10.3.5-1` **did not work** while `yum install MariaDB-server-10.3.5` **worked** well.

Comment: if you have the package installed and want to install a previous version of the package - `yum install` won't work, `yum downgrade` should be used instead.

Answer (score 12):

Another option, you can download `rpm` file then instruct `yum` to do a `localinstall`:

```
yum localinstall /path/to/package.rpm
```

A good place to get the packages you need is rpmfind.com and search the package name.

Comment: Is there a URL which contains most if not all versions of the rpm files?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow: http://www.rpmfind.net/

Comment: There's also `yum --downloadonly <package>`, followed by `yum localinstall <path to package>`, too. You can also use the utility `yumdownloader <package>` too.