# Emacs dependency on librsvg2 error on Centos 6.6

Tags: centos, yum

I'm trying to install emacs and graphviz on my CentosBox. Its failing to resolve librsvg2:

`$ sudo yum install emacs graphviz
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.vooservers.com
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirror.ukhost4u.com
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.coreix.net
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emacs.x86_64 1:23.1-25.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: emacs-common = 1:23.1-25.el6 for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: m17n-db-datafiles for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librsvg2 for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libotf.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm17n-flt.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm17n-core.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
---> Package graphviz.x86_64 0:2.26.0-10.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: graphviz-2.26.0-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) for package: graphviz-2.26.0-10.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emacs.x86_64 1:23.1-25.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librsvg2 for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
---> Package emacs-common.x86_64 1:23.1-25.el6 will be installed
---> Package gd.x86_64 0:2.0.35-11.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXaw.x86_64 0:1.0.11-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libotf.x86_64 0:0.9.9-3.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package m17n-db-datafiles.noarch 0:1.5.5-1.1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: m17n-db = 1.5.5-1.1.el6 for package: m17n-db-datafiles-1.5.5-1.1.el6.noarch
---> Package m17n-lib.x86_64 0:1.5.5-2.el6_1.1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emacs.x86_64 1:23.1-25.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librsvg2 for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64
---> Package m17n-db.noarch 0:1.5.5-1.1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:emacs-23.1-25.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: librsvg2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

I thought maybe there was another version of emacs available. So I [check as per this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specifc-version-of-package-x).

`$ yum --showduplicates list  emacs
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.coreix.net
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
Available Packages
emacs.x86_64                                                                                         1:23.1-25.el6                                                                                           base`

So if its the emacs that's part of the base centos package, why does it depend on librsvg2, which isn't part of centos?

Answer (score 0):

When I looked up [emacs via rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/6.6/i386/Packages/emacs-23.1-25.el6.i686.html) I do see a dependency on the librsvg2 rpm. Try running `rpmquery --requires` and see if you don't see it as well.

In either case it is pretty simple to run `yum -y install librsvg2` to add that package.