# How do I find available versions of package for downgrade?

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade

I am having issues with an update of the ImageMagick package breaking 3rd party software on a CentOS 6.x server. I know that some prior version of ImageMagick worked OK.

How do I find out which versions of ImageMagick are available to perform a `yum downgrade` operation ?

```
$> sudo yum downgrade ImageMagick-c++
Only Upgrade available on package: ImageMagick-c++-6.7.2.7-2.el6.i686
Nothing to do
```

And, if I try the following, I get:

```
$> sudo yum --showduplicates list ImageMagick-c++ | expand
Installed Packages
ImageMagick-c++.i686                      6.7.2.7-2.el6                    @base

Available Packages
ImageMagick-c++.i686                      6.7.2.7-2.el6                    base 
ImageMagick-c++.x86_64                    6.7.2.7-2.el6                    base
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x

Comment: @JRFerguson I think my question is distinct based on this comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x#comment247606_151690

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade is very straightforward when package have not any dependencies, which affect the downgrade and is more difficult with packages that have dependencies. YUM downgrade does not resolve dependencies automatically, so it must be done manually. If you wan to that then use `yum downgrade package`.
(kindly tell the error message, i will edit my answer then)

Comment: your problem seems to be of hardware compatibility of package.check out this  RedHat  thread [link](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2006-October/msg03684.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the i686 version also run on x86-64? I don't see how there should be any hardware compatibility issue with i686.

Comment: i686 is actually a 32-bit instruction set (part of the x86 family line), while x86_64 is a 64-bit instruction set (also referred to as amd64).

Comment: "These 64bit processors are fully backward compatible with their 32bit
predecessors.  So if you have a 64bit AMD Athlon 64 or Intel EM64T
processor, it is up to you whether to install the 64bit x86_64 OS or
the 32bit i386/i686 OS... Another thing worth mentioning is that the 64bit x86_64 distribution
does come with runtime compatibility for 32bit x86 applications, so
it is not entirely a all or nothing decision."

Comment: Indeed, the CPU can support a 32bit system, but it also requires all the 32bit libraries to work. So, you may even have a double system (32/64bit) but, you will need a double installation at least for the libraries.