# Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon

Tags: centos, yum, services, openldap

Using Centos 7 and following steps for openldap server configurations.i am facing this problem

```
[root@linux1 ~]# systemctl restart slapd
Job for slapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@linux1 ~]#
[root@linux1 ~]#
[root@linux1 ~]#
[root@linux1 ~]# systemctl status slapd
● slapd.service - OpenLDAP Server Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-05-13 03:21:41 EDT; 7min ago
     Docs: man:slapd
           man:slapd-config
           man:slapd-hdb
           man:slapd-mdb
           file:///usr/share/doc/openldap-servers/guide.html
  Process: 2781 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2767 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/openldap/check-config.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 13 03:21:40 linux1.learnitguide.net runuser[2770]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
May 13 03:21:40 linux1.learnitguide.net slapd[2781]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (Apr 12 2018 19:17:38) $
                                                             mockbuild@x86-01.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd
May 13 03:21:40 linux1.learnitguide.net slapd[2781]: ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"
May 13 03:21:40 linux1.learnitguide.net slapd[2781]: ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif"
May 13 03:21:41 linux1.learnitguide.net slapd[2781]: tlsmc_cert_create_hash_symlink: ERROR: OS error: Permission denied
May 13 03:21:41 linux1.learnitguide.net slapd[2781]: Could not get the realpath: No such file or directory
May 13 03:21:41 linux1.learnitguide.net systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 13 03:21:41 linux1.learnitguide.net systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
May 13 03:21:41 linux1.learnitguide.net systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
May 13 03:21:41 linux1.learnitguide.net systemd[1]: slapd.service failed.
[root@linux1 ~]#
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not have the "tlsmc_cert_create_hash_symlink: ERROR: OS error: Permission denied" issue, but the same error message "Could not get the realpath: No such file or directory".

This affects the latest Openldap Version for Centos7

```
rpm -qa | grep openldap                                                                                
    openldap-clients-2.4.44-13.el7.x86_64                                                                                                  
    openldap-servers-2.4.44-13.el7.x86_64                                                                     
    openldap-2.4.44-13.el7.x86_64

ls /var/lib/ldap/
```

For you as information, it seems that the DB_CONFIG in /var/lib/ldap for this version is empty.
I was not able to find the cause. Creating an own DB_CONFIG and changing the ldap.conf did not fix the issue.

---

So the dirty solution: Downgrade OpenLdap.

```
mkdir /tmp/openldap/
cd /tmp/openldap/
wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/openldap-clients-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64.rpm

wget https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/openldap-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64.rpm

wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/openldap-servers-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64.rpm

yum downgrade ./openldap-*
systemctl start slapd.service
```

Sorry, I didnt test other versions and the source is questionable. But LDAP starts then.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem, we just yum -y upgrade and after that ldap works fine.

Answer (score 2):

if you are CentOS 7 just enter these command and all thing  will be good

```
    yum update
    cp /usr/share/openldap-servers/DB_CONFIG.example /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG
    chown ldap:ldap /var/lib/ldap/*
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of SELinux.
You should make a policy for slapd.

```
#grep slapd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow

#============= slapd_t ==============
allow slapd_t slapd_tmp_t:lnk_file create;
```

After confirm above, make a policy.

```
# grep slapd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m slapd > slapd.te
# grep slapd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M slapd
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i slapd.pp
# semodule -i slapd.pp
```

After that you may have another TSL problem. You need to allow slapd to read files.
Well, you could solve that same way. With audit2allow, rebuild policy.

Answer (score 0):

Taking tips from [How can I instruct yum to install a specific version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x) I did the following:

```
yum --showduplicates list openldap-servers
```

I got the following:

```
openldap-servers.x86_64                                           2.4.40-9.el7_2                                            ol7_latest 
openldap-servers.x86_64    2.4.40-13.el7      ol7_latest 
openldap-servers.x86_64    2.4.44-5.el7       ol7_latest  -> Last run version
openldap-servers.x86_64    2.4.44-13.el7      ol7_latest  -> Works
openldap-servers.x86_64    2.4.44-15.el7_5    ol7_latest  -> DOES NOT WORK
```

I used the older version of openldap-servers using:

```
yum install openldap-servers-2.4.44-13.el7
```

And was able to avoid the issue.