# How can I instruct yum to install a specific version of package X if package X is not available in list?

Tags: centos

Below is available package-

Available Packages
haproxy.x86_64             1.5.18-9.el7_9.1              rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms

Comment: want to install  latest version , please suggest possible way , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for available packages of any application.

```
$ yum --showduplicates list haproxy | expand

[4abc@xyz abc]$ yum --showduplicates list haproxy | expand
Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:34 ago on Fri 18 Nov 2022 12:12:51 PM UTC.
Available Packages
haproxy.x86_64                      1.8.27-5.el8                       appstream
```

Ex:

```
yum --showduplicates list iptables-services | expand
```

Output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:50:05 ago on Fri 04 Nov 2022 10:45:21 AM UTC.
Available Packages
iptables-services.x86_64                   1.8.4-22.el8                   baseos
```

Then run command with version of available package:

```
sudo yum install <package name>-<version info>
```

Ref link: [How can I instruct yum to install a specific version of package X?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x)