# How to get `yum list` output to stay on one line when getting output via remote ssh command?

Tags: ssh, terminal, pipe, yum

When I SSH to a machine with `ssh machine` and run `yum list` it outputs everything that's installed as expected, and importantly every item is on one line like so:

```
xz-devel.i386                                                                                                        4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5                                                                  base            
xz-devel.x86_64                                                                                                      4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5                                                                  base            
xz-libs.i386                                                                                                         4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5                                                                  base            
xz-lzma-compat.x86_64                                                                                                4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5                                                                  base
```

But upon doing it remotely with `ssh machine 'yum list'` or even piping it to grep while on the server with `yum list | grep xz -C 3` the output's lines are "truncated" and made much shorter, like so:

```
xz-devel.i386                              4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5
                                                                       base     
xz-devel.x86_64                            4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5
                                                                       base     
xz-libs.i386                               4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5
                                                                       base     
xz-lzma-compat.x86_64                      4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5
                                                                       base
```

How can I make the size of the line not shrink like this? My end desire is to pipe this to `tee` and then do some processing on the outputted file for all my hosts via ansible.

It seems that this is occurring due to some sort of "virtual terminal" as part of the SSH/piping because I can get the same behavior if I shrink my terminal size where the lines break when running `yum list`. Thus I'd assume that the addition of the pipe somehow tells `yum list` that the width of the terminal is only X columns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964478/rearranging-file-into-three-columns/18964631#18964631

Comment: cannot reproduce on centos 7

Comment: Note also that `yum list` does not list everything that is installed (it lists everything that is *available*).  For a list of installed packages, you probably want `rpm -qa`, the output of which is much more suitable for scripting parsing.  In particular, also see the documentation for the `--queryformat` option to the `rpm` command.

Comment: Does `ssh -t machine 'yum list'` solve the problem?

Comment: @thrig thanks for the link, that resolved it for me

Comment: idk if this would solve in your specific situation, but often piping to `cat` is enough to tell a program that stdout isn't a tty, and therefore don't prettify output. w/ yum, for example, doing that will prevent right-justification of the trailing columns.

Answer (score 9):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964478/rearranging-file-into-three-columns/18964631#18964631) provided in the comments by @thrig I was able to get it to output correctly by doing

```
yum list installed | xargs -n3 | column -t
```

Comment: I'd be curious to hear if my proposal (in a comment above) works for you; that'd be way simpler and catch the real cause why combining ssh and yum in a single step gives a different result than interactively logging in and executing yum remotely. I don't have a remote machine to test my theory.

Comment: Slightly modified: `yum list installed | tail -n +5 | xargs -n3 | column -t | less` cleans off the crud for unregistered redhat systems.

Comment: @egmont I tried your idea, and it worked quite well.

Answer (score 4):

Install expect, which comes with unbuffer(1), and run:

```
# unbuffer yum repolist
```

Answer (score 3):

I fought with this today (during a `yum check-update` operation) and after finding a ["CLOSED NOTABUG" bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=584525) and various [python hacks](https://james.fedorapeople.org/yum/plugins/ttysz.py), I came up with yet another workaround:

```
script -q -c "stty cols 150; yum check-update" /dev/null > /path/to/output.txt 2>&1
```

or:

```
script -q -c "stty cols 150; yum check-update" /path/to/output.txt > /dev/null
```

150 was an arbitrarily large-enough number to prevent wrapping; adjust that upwards if needed.  The `-q` option inhibits the initial "Script started on $(date)" line, if you use a non-null output filename.

For the original problem, the line would be:

```
script -q -c "stty cols 150; yum list" /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers worked for me on RHEL 7.7. So decided to use `sed` to concatenate next line to all lines that lack `@` character.

```
yum list installed | sed '/^[^@]*$/{N;s/\n//}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `repoquery` command to produce parsable output. For instance:

```
repoquery '*' --queryformat='%{name} %{evr} %{from_repo}' | column -t
```

gives:

```
0ad                0.0.23b-13.fc32  fedora
0ad                0.0.23b-17.fc32  updates
0ad-data           0.0.23b-4.fc32   fedora
0xFFFF             0.8-3.fc32       fedora
2048-cli           0.9.1-9.fc32     fedora
2048-cli-nocurses  0.9.1-9.fc32     fedora
2048-cli-sdl       0.9.1-9.fc32     fedora
2ping              4.3-6.fc32       fedora
2ping              4.5-1.fc32       updates
389-ds-base        1.4.3.18-1.fc32  updates
```

... and so on.

(Unlike `dnf`/`yum`, repoquery doesn't eliminate duplicate packages in its output)

Comment: When running on CentOS 7, I found that `%{from_repo}` didn't work. I had to use `%{ui_from_repo}` instead. Otherwise `repoquery` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I always forget when to use repoid/from_repo/ui_from_repo myself!