# Change output width (columns) of processes created by gnu parallel

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to save the output of a command into files and it seems to work fine. However, when opening one of the files, I can see that output was limited to 80 characters width. How can I ensure that the output is not being wrapped? I've tried to put a `tput rmam;` at the beginning of the shell script but it doesn't seem to change the output behavior.

**Script**:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CPUS=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "processor" | wc -l)
ansible-doc -l | cut -d " " -f1 > modules.txt
parallel --tmpdir src/yaml-snippets --files -a modules.txt -j$CPUS  ansible-doc -s {}
```

Example output:

```
- name: Module to manage datacenter quotas in oVirt/RHV
  ovirt_quota:
      auth:                  # (required) Dictionary with values needed to
                               create HTTP/HTTPS
                               connection to
                               oVirt: `username'
                               [`required'] -
                               The name of the
                               user, something
                               like
                               `admin@internal'.
                               Default value is
                               set by
                               `OVIRT_USERNAME'
                               environment
                               variable. `passwo
```

Comment: Is GNU parallel involved here? Does the wrapped formatting come from the `ansible-doc -l` command, or from the parallel'd `ansible-doc -s` command? Can you reproduce it without GNU parallel?

Comment: Given that `yum` uses python, I'd be curious if [this hack/workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499556/117549) also works for `ansible-doc`.

Comment: The actual output is generated by `ansible-doc -s ovirt_quota`. However, executing it plain on the shell and executing it through parallel have different output size.

Comment: Using the referenced hack worked @JeffSchaller :
`script -q -c "stty cols 1000; ansible-doc -s $1 > src/yaml-snippets/$1.yml"` this line is called by `cat modules.txt | xargs -t -n 1 -P$CPUS $DIR/generate.sh`

Comment: Please feel free to self-answer, since I can't test in a similar environment to yours. Thanks!

Comment: Just to point this out, parallel will figure out how many CPUs there are and run that many jobs in parallel with no `-j` flag, or if you want to explicitly say it, `-j100%` (which is the default).
    
Also grep has a `-c` flag to count the number of matches, so `grep -c "processor" /proc/cpuinfo` will give you a count of the number of processors.